# Translate this html to haml

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I tried to translate this html to haml. I used http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/ and http://htmltohaml.com/ with no success.

```
<li class="nav-item btn-group" data-behavior="notifications" data-notifications='<%= render template: "notifications/index", formats: [:json] %>'>
</li>
```

They give me both this :

```
%li.nav-item.btn-group{"data-behavior" => "notifications", "data-notifications" => render template: "notifications/index", formats: [:json]}
```

But i have an SyntaxError running this.
Could someone help me ?

Comment: https://github.com/haml/html2haml

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thanks but i just need to translate this line not an entire project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%li.nav-item.btn-group{ :data => { :behavior => "notifications", :notifications => (render template: "notifications/index", formats: [:json]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one works,

```
%li.nav-item.btn-group{"data-behavior" => "notifications", "data-notifications" => (render partial: "notifications/index")}
```